# Traffic Light task GCSE next week

Tags: javascript, html

Having trouble sorting out this problem. I have a GCSE next week and I need to get this sorted!! The task is to create a traffic light (an image) that changes color to green, then amber, then red, then amber, then green and so on every time the user clicks the button.
This is my code so far

```js
function green() {
    document.getElementById("trafficlight").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/N/Y/e/6/U/i/green-light-md.png"
}

function amber() {
    document.getElementById("trafficlight").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/f/a/2/11949849771043985234traffic_light_red_dan_ge_01.svg.med.png"
}

function red() {
    document.getElementById("trafficlight").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/1/7/4/11949849782053089133traffic_light_yellow_dan_01.svg.med.png"
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/v/d/O/m/p/E/traffic-vector-md.png" id="trafficlight" />
<button onclick="green();amber();red()" type="button">Click to change colour!</button>
```

Comment: So, what is the question? If it is “Why does `onclick` handler not calling functions in round-robin fashion?” — then that is because it calls them all one by one, in successive order, and only the last has the effect (btw, your `red()` sets amber color, and `amber()` sets red). You should choose the branch manually based on a persistent variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.
You can use a switch case, and a global variable that is updated every time you click. [Switch-case example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)